# is there any way to crop an jpg image captured by esp cam?

Tags: c, arduino, esp32

//I am trying to crop an image captured by espcam the image is in a jpg format I would like to crop it. As the image is stored as a single-dimensional array I tried to rearrange the elements in the array but no changes occurred //

I have cropped the image in RGB565 but I am struggling to understand the single-dimensional array(image buffer)

```
camera_config_t config;

  config.ledc_channel = LEDC_CHANNEL_0;
  config.ledc_timer = LEDC_TIMER_0; 
  config.pin_d0 = Y2_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d1 = Y3_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d2 = Y4_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d3 = Y5_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d4 = Y6_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d5 = Y7_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d6 = Y8_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d7 = Y9_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_xclk = XCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pclk = PCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_vsync = VSYNC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_href = HREF_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sscb_sda = SIOD_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sscb_scl = SIOC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pwdn = PWDN_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_reset = RESET_GPIO_NUM;
  config.xclk_freq_hz = 20000000;
  config.pixel_format = PIXFORMAT_RGB565; 
  config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_SVGA;
  // config.jpeg_quality = 10;
  config.fb_count = 2;
    
  esp_err_t result = esp_camera_init(&config);
   
  if (result != ESP_OK) {
    return false;
  }
    camera_fb_t * fb = NULL;
    fb = esp_camera_fb_get();
    if (!fb)
     {
        Serial.println("Camera capture failed");
     }
```

the Fb buffer is a single-dimensional array I want to extract each individual RGB value.

Comment: If the image is in Jpeg format, you first have to decode it to get RGB data. Do you work with RGB data of the jpeg image, or directly the jpeg data ?

Answer (score 0):

JPG is a compressed format, meaning that your rows and columns are not corresponding to what you would see by displaying a 1:1 grid on the screen. You need to convert it to the plain RGB (or equivalents) format and then copy it.

JPG achieves compression by splitting the image into YCbCR components, using a mathematical transformation and then filtering. For additional information I refer to [this page](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Eweb6140/TopTenAlgorithms/JPEG.html).

Luckily you can follow [this tutorial](https://www.deviceplus.com/arduino/jpeg-decoding-on-arduino-tutorial/#Decoding) to do the inverse JPEG transformation on an Arduino (tip: forget to do this in real time, unless your time constraints are very relaxed).

The idea is to use a library that converts the JPEG image into an array of data:

> Using the library is fairly simple: we give it the JPEG file, and the library will start generating arrays of pixels – so called Minimum Coded Units, or MCUs for short. The MCU is a block of 16 by 8 pixels. The functions in the library will return the color value for each pixel as 16-bit color value. The upper 5 bits are the red value, the middle 6 are green and the lower 5 are blue. Now we can send these values by any sort of communication channel we like.

For your use case you won't send the data through the communication channel, but rather store it in a local array by pushing the blocks into adjacent tiles, then do the crop.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the output format table for the [ESP32 Camera Driver](https://github.com/espressif/esp32-camera) one can see that most output formats are non-jpeg. If you can handle a RAW format instead (it will be slower to save/transfer, and be MUCH larger) then that would allow you to more easily crop the image by make a copy with a couple of loops.  JPEG is compressed and not easily cropped. The page linked also mentions this:

- Using YUV or RGB puts a lot of strain on the chip because writing to PSRAM is not particularly fast. The result is that image data might be missing. This is particularly true if WiFi is enabled. If you need RGB data, it is recommended that JPEG is captured and then turned into RGB using `fmt2rgb888` or `fmt2bmp/frame2bmp`

If you are using `PIXFORMAT_RGB565` (which means each pixel value will be kept in TWO bytes, and the image is not jpeg compressed) and `FRAMESIZE_SVGA` (800x600 pixels), you should be able to access the framebuffer as a two-dimensional array if you want:

```
uint16_t *buffer = fb->buf;
uint16_t pxl = buffer[row * 800 + column];  // 800 is the SVGA width
// pxl now contains 5 R-bits, 6 G-bits, 5 B-bits
```

Comment: thankyou for your support I am capturing in rgb565 and getting a single dimension array but I am confused with understanding the array have you got any info on how to read the array i am confused about how r g b is stored I want to convert to HSV so.. thankyou

Comment: @the-terminal-guy you should probably post _some of the code_ showing how you setup the camera and retrieve frames

Comment: i have added some part of my code here

Comment: @the-terminal-guy I added a suggestion

Comment: thankyou for your suggestion I'm a bit unclear about the row and column,considering that fb is a single-dimensional array

Comment: @the-terminal-guy The code I suggested still treats the buffer as a one-dimensional array.  The row and column can be used to find the exact position in the one-dimensional array. You only need to provide row and column.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what kind of hardware (camera and board) you are using.
I'm basing this on the OV2640 camera module because it's the one I've been working with. It delivers the image to the frame buffer already encoded, so I'm guessing this might be what you are facing.

Trying to crop the image after it has been encoded can be tricky, but you might be able to instruct the camera chip to only deliver a certain part of the sensor output in the first place using a [window function](https://github.com/espressif/esp32-camera/issues/224#issuecomment-788106836).

The easiest way to access this setting is to define a function to access this:

```
void setWindow(int resolution , int xOffset, int yOffset, int xLength, int yLength) {
    sensor_t * s = esp_camera_sensor_get();
    resolution = 0;
    s->set_res_raw(s, resolution, 0, 0, 0, xOffset, yOffset, xLength, yLength, xLength, yLength, true, true);
}

/*
* resolution = 0 \\ 1600 x 1200
* resolution = 1 \\  800 x  600
* resolution = 2 \\  400 x  296
*/
```

where (xOffset,yOffset) is the origin of the window in pixels and (xLength,yLength) is the size of the window in pixels. Be aware that changing the resolution will effectively overwrite these settings. Otherwise this works great for me, although for some reason only if the aspect ratio of 4:3 is preserved in the window size.